# How should I post an answer to a question that hasnt been asked yet?

Tags: discussion, new-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I answer my own questions, even those where I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

We've implemented AppFabric and I dont see too many questions about it yet.. I figured I can take a preliminary action by posting some answers to the puzzles that I've already solved.

Thanks.

Comment: If the questions are on-topic you can always ask and answer your own questions... as long as it is not just self-promotion, it should be fine (and on-topic of course).